# How to convert batch script if statement to powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a batch script. I want to change it to powershell script. Is my code below the same purpose?

My batch script

```
IF %ODM% EQU 1 (
    ECHO #ODM# detected
    IF %Stage% EQU 10 (
        ECHO  Stage Code 10
    )
)
```

Powershell script

```
If ($ODM = "1")
{Write-Host "#ODM# detected"}
if ($Stge = "10")
{Write-Host "Stage Code 10"}
```

Comment: The equals comparison operator in PowerShell is `-eq` and not the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: are %ODM% and %Stage% environment-variables ? if so, you'll need to change $ODM to $env:ODM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, it looks like the batch code you supplied had nested if statements whereas you PowerShell code just had two seperate if statements.

So you would be looking at something like this:

```
if ($ODM -eq "1"){
    Write-Host "$ODM detected"
    if ($Stge -eq "10"){
        Write-Host "Stage code 10"
    }
}
```